# Wiring a ceiling fan/light to two 3 way switches

Tags: ceiling-fan, multiway-switch

Wiring a ceiling fan/light combo with TWO 3 way switches. The fan/light is pull string type.
[image: room with two switches and ceiling fan]

[image: diagram of description]

[image: first 3 way switch with 14-2 cable line/power, and two 14-3 cables]

The First 3 way Switch box has ONE (line/power) 14-2 cable plus ground, and TWO 14-3 cables plus ground wires.

The 14-2 (line/power) BLACK wire is pigtailed to BOTH the First and Second 14-3 black wires, then to the bottom black screw on First 3 way switch.

The White wire 14-2 cable is pigtailed to the First 14-3 white wire only.

The Red wire of same 14-3 is to First 3 way switch left side brass screw.

The First 14-3 (said pigtailed black/white from 14-2 line/power) routes to the ceiling fan/light junction box where it is pigtailed black-black, white-white, red-red to an additional 14-3 wire then pigtailed to the fan/light, matching wires black-black, white-white,with red to blue.
The additional 14-3 cable from ceiling fan j-box continues on to power two recessed can lights.

BOTH fan/light AND recessed can lights turn on when First 3 way switch is turned on.

Back at the light switch, the Second 14-3 cable has the black wire pigtailed to First 14-3, the red wire to the brass screw (traveler) of First 3 way switch, and the white wire capped off to NOTHING.

This Second 14-3 cable is routed over to the Second 3 way switch box (with only this one 14-3 cable in it) and ends there with the black wire to bottom black screw, red wire to right side brass traveler screw and white wire to left side brass traveler screw.

This Second 3 way switch does NOT power the fan/light and canned lights as it should, working in conjunction with the First 3 way switch. 
Only the first switch will turn fan/light and canned light on simultaneously.
So basically a three wire up to fan and back to switch, then to second switch and back on a three wire.
Questions would be, should black wires at first switch be pigtailed in this fashion? And why would the second 14-3 wire be capped alone to nothing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's really hard to follow what you mean; would you break this into paragraphs and add a diagram or two? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are you saying you have two 3-way switches in total, or FOUR 3-way switches providing separate control of two different devices?    Also, **3-way switches don't have silver screws.  They have 1 black and 2 brass screws only (ignoring ground).  Also, travelers are always in pairs.  Are these smart switches?**

Comment: Hello again. An anonymous user just added pictures and a diagram; I presumed this was you, so I approved it. If it was, then please make sure you login as yourself before making edits; that way reviewers won't have to guess. If it wasn't, please let me know and I'll get it reverted. And, please take the tour!